# How create a function with method patch

Tags: python, python-3.x, patch, put

I have a function with a method put, but a want other function with method patch, but I don't know how do it.

Here a method put:

@app.route('/api/v1/benefit/', methods=['PUT'])
def update_benefited(id):
    benefited = Benefited.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    if benefited is None:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Benefited does not exists'}), 404

```
json = request.get_json(force=True)
if json.get('username') is None:
    return jsonify({'message': 'Bad request'}), 400

benefited.username = json['username']
benefited.age = json['age']
benefited.job = json['job']

benefited.update()

return jsonify({'benefited': benefited.json()})
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful it you add which language you are referring to in the Question title as well as in the tag for experts to find your question

Comment: the language is python